# Replacing first record with newly created record instead created new row in excell sheet

Tags: excel

I have 4 sheets Name Project Creation, Ashok, Master and Sheet 
Main

Sheet Contains about project details along with data and some columns data will be copied to project sheet at that time structure of the project (Header names and design with merged rows) and will load few columns data from main sheet if I insert new row in main sheet it should update project sheet with few columns data but using child sheet structure (Empty design template).

I implemented the following code, problem is each time it is replacing the first record (It is merged rows) I mean if insert second row it is replacing.

Please help me and refer the images

```
Private Sub CopyDataFrmExcell()
Dim xRCount As Long
    Dim xSht As Worksheet
     Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xNSht As Worksheet

  Dim lrs As Long, lrd As Long, p As Long, brd As Long, krd As Long, LastRowNumber As Long

lrs = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(Sheets("ProjectCreation").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets("Ashok")  'longer to type than "Summary"
    For p = 2 To lrs 'assumes header in row 1

        If p = 2 Then
            lrd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           Sheets("Ashok").Cells(5, 7).Value = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(p, 9).Value
            brd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(5, 8).Value = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(p, 10).Value
            krd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(5, 9).Value = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(p, 11).Value

           Else
           Sheets("Sheet4").Select
            Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:Y6").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Ashok").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
           Sheets("Ashok").Select
           LastRowNumber = Sheets("Ashok").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row     
          lrd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         Sheets("Ashok").Cells(LastRowNumber + 1, 7).Value = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(p, 9).Value
          brd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
          .Cells(LastRowNumber + 1, 8).Value = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(p, 10).Value
           krd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(LastRowNumber + 1, 9).Value = Sheets("ProjectCreation").Cells(p, 11).Value    
        End If
Next p
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code below is in no way intended to run. My intention is to provide a base from which to instill sense into it. I hope that you will be the one to do the instilling.

```
Private Sub CopyDataFrmExcell()

    Dim WsPro As Worksheet
    Dim WsSum As Worksheet
    Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long
    Dim RlPro As Long, RlSum As Long

    Set WsPro = Worksheets("ProjectCreation")
    Set WsSum = Worksheets("Ashok")                 'longer to type than "Summary"
    Set Ws4 = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    With WsPro
        RlPro = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With WsSum
        For R = 2 To RlPro                          'assumes header in row 1
            If R = 2 Then
                WsPro.Range("I2:K2").Copy .Cells(5, 7)
            Else
                Ws4.Range("A1:Y6").Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                RlSum = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                WsPro.Range(Cells(R, 9), Cells(R, 11)).Copy .Cells(RlSum + 1, 7)
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

As you see, I have tried to give some meaningful names to the variables. You will now be able to identify them from their names. That, in turn, enables you to read the narrative of the code which still makes no sense.

The core of the code loops through every row in WsPro and then does something in WsSum. This appears illogical. OK, you want to copy the header from WsPro to WsSum. That doesn't really need to be in a loop, does it? Then you want to copy range Ws4.Range("A1:Y6") to the end of WsSum. Fair enough, but why must this be done multiple times depending on the number of rows in WsPro? Finally you want to paste each row of WsPro to the end of WsSum, following the range from Ws4. Perhaps Ws4 should not always be the same sheet.

The code is very small and concise now. It should be easy to amend it in a way that it does what you intended it to do. Therefore I hope that my input will help you.

Comment: I am getting error as "We cant do it that to a  merged cell ", project creation data is in normal cell which is pasted to merged cells in "Ashok" sheet please help me to fix this issue as soon as possible

Comment: in if condition i have to copy the other template in to WSSum and else condition I have to copy structure from Ws4 in to WsSum each case data will come from Wspro only,Struture of the WSSum will be designed using both Ws4 and WsMaster(which is not avail in your code but i have that in my code in the if conditon area).

Comment: Else part Ws4 not copying to destination only if part work sheet structure copying.Please consider this issue as well with the above code